# Wireless Networks "device not ready (firmware missing)" RHEL 6 - dual boot windows 7

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ntfs, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have RHEL 6 installed on my Dell Laptop. It's a dual boot environment, Windows 7 and RHEL 6. It's a 32 bit system.

I only have my phone to use internet on my computer, thus I must use only wireless on my computer to get connected to internet. But RHEL 6 gives me an error "Wireless Networks (device not ready (firmware missing))".
I tried some forums and came to know that I'll have to install some other software, some firmware. I have Broadcom BCM 4312 802.11 b/g LP-PHY.

Using my friend's laptop I downloaded the packages and saved them on my Transcend (NTFS) hard drive. But again, I'm unable to mount the hard drive too. It says

> unknown file system 'ntfs'.

I tried some forums and again I'll have to download some EPEL packages to be able to mount ntfs disk.

But everything gets back to internet. How do i resolve the firmware missing error  without Internet or a hard drive.

I'm trying to create a DVD or CD for the missing packages and I'll try to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to download the following two packages:

- http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o
- http://mirror2.openwrt.org/sources/broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2

and had to transfer them to a flash drive and then to the root's home folder.

I had to run the following commands as root:

```
tar -xjvf broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2
b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o
b43-fwcutter --unsupported -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5/driver/wl_apsta_mimo.o
chmod 775 /lib/firmware/b43
chmod 775 /lib/firmware/b43legacy  
reboot
```